# How to generate new tensor by given indexes and tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor like this:

```
x = torch.tensor([[3, 4, 2], [0, 1, 5]])
```

and I have a indexes like this:

```
ind = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
```

then I want to generate a new tensor by `x` and `ind`:

```
z = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5])
```

I impement it with python like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import torch

x = torch.tensor([[3, 4, 2], [0, 1, 5]])
ind = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

z = torch.zeros_like(x)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        z[i, j] = x[ind[i][j]][j]

print(z)
```

I want to know how to solve this by `pytorch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather)

```py
In [1]: import torch

In [2]: x = torch.tensor([[3, 4, 2], [0, 1, 5]])

In [3]: ind = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

In [4]: torch.gather(x, 0, ind)
Out[4]:
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]])
```